# animation panel keeps displaying

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

**Update 1:**

Found it's CSS issue, so here is what I tried to solve this issue:

```
.default-details {
  .....
    margin-top: 107%;
}

@keyframes openning {
    from {
        margin-top: 107%;
    }
    to {  
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes closing {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    to { 
        margin-top: 107%;
    }
}
```

---

css:

```
.default-details {
  ...
    display: none !important;
}

.open-animation {
    animation: open 2s ;
}

.close-animation {
    animation: close 2s ;
}

@keyframes open {
    from {
        display: none!important;
        margin-top: 107%;
    }
    to {  
        margin-top: 0;
        display: block;
    }
}

@keyframes close {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    to { 
        display: none !important;
        margin-top: 107%;
    }
}
```

The intended behavior should be :

1. Click button: the details panel slides up, fully covers the card.
2. Click the panel: the panel slides down and disappears.

(Like the Materialize Css Card Reveal: https://react-materialize.github.io/#/cards)

What it behaves now:
It does the animation, but at end the details panel always goes back to cover the card.

Comment: Have you tried doing the css animations another way? Maybe it's just a css problem, not a react issue. The reason why you're getting "after true" is because setState is asynchronous. So it's not going to show up right away. Try doing the console.log in your render method instead if you want to know if it changed or not... which I'm guessing it did

Comment: Hi @user222957 I've tried, it changed in a callback function.So how should I write up the css animation?

Comment: Hi @user222957 you are correct. I removed the animation and only switch the display between block and none, it works correctly, but I still want the animation effect. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out what's the REAL issue.

After update 1, it animation works almost correctly except after the details panel opened(the opening animation which is sliding up works) the details panel disappeared.

The reason for that is once animation ends, the value of the animated css property comes back to its original value.

To prevent this, add:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
```

Job's done~! :)

Answer (score 1):

Like user222957 mentioned in your comments the problem is that `.setState` is asynchronous.

Also you can't animate the `display` property, try `opacity` (`0%`/`100%`) and `visibility` (`hidden`/`visible`).

Comment: Hi there, if I use opacity, the effect becomes fade in and out. but I want Slide up and down. Also, I have removed the "display"

Comment: @Franva well you didn't remove it from the code in question. In that case you can just animate `height` (and only height, it won't work well with `margin`)

Comment: hi Killah, now I updated my question. You can see my new CSS in Update 1.  If I animate height, the effect becomes: details panel will stick to the top and it will slide down when opening and slide up when closing. this is opposite effect.  I want the details panel slide up from the bottom when opening and slide down to get outside of the bottom when closing. Hopefully, what I said makes sense to you.

Comment: and I found one more issue. Once animation ended, the height/margin-top comes back to its original default value.

Comment: I up-voted your answer to thank you for your help :) I have figured out the issue.